# How can I get the name of an image button in Android?

Tags: android

How can I get name of an image button when I know its id?

Comment: u require the drawable used or the text written in the image button?

Comment: What exactly do you mean: "name of an image button"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the code snippet below:

```
getResources().getResourceName(id);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  But my problem is not regarding of the reference but the real problem is ...in android i have two buttons.  If i click on first button i to zoomin the second button.  Is it possible. I think i am clear about it...

Answer (score 1):

An imagebutton has an image instead of text, and does not really have a 'name'.
If you mean 'reference', you can do this:

```
(ImageButton) button = findViewById(R.id.YourId);
```